What is the difference between ''on the loose'' and at large?
The reason why I am asking is that I did some research on the difference and what I found were two explanations that just don't tie in with one another.
According to one school of thought, both idioms can be used to mean that either convict who was in prison but escaped or a person who hasn't been caught yet is still free.
Whereas some native speakers assert that ''on the loose'' is used exclusively when someone has escaped and ''at large'' is used when someone hasn't been captured yet and have never been in captivity before.
So, according to the second set of people, if a bank robber who had been imprisoned prior to his escape but has broken out is on the loose.
And, let's say, a serial killer who hasn't been caught yet (the police are still trying to find out who the serial killer is and they haven't arrested him/her yet) is at large.
Which school of thought is correct or more common?

I'd be interested to know where you saw these expressions being used.  Why did you start researching them today?

An ambassador at large is not one on the loose. You really need to look this stuff up, as several of us have told you several times.

The idiom "at large" is used only for criminals that the police want to arrest but don't know where they are.  They might have escaped from prison, or they might not have been arrested yet.

The killer was still at large on Monday evening.

But if the police know where the criminal is, then they are not "at large".  A criminal that has taken a hostage and is surrounded by police is no longer "at large".
"On the loose" is more often used for animals than people: "There's a dog on the loose in the park."  When used for criminals it has almost the same meaning as "at large", except it might be used for a criminal that being actively chased.

The driver was still on the loose at 8 pm, but police were closing in and an arrest was made at 9 o'clock.


Thank you but it still doesn't make entirely sense. So ''on the loose'' isn't used to say that a prisoner who broke out is now free?

As my answer says, when applied to a criminal, "on the loose" means almost exactly the same as "at large".  So both phrases could be used to describe a prisoner who broke out, is now free, and whose whereabouts are unknown.

Ok but what about criminals whose identities are still unknown and are yet to be locked up and thus still free?

Yes, you could use both "at large" and "on the loose", As my answer says, when applied to a criminal, "on the loose" means almost exactly the same as "at large"  "There's a killer on the loose"/  "There's a killer at large"  but we don't know who it is.

No, your first sentence is not true: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambassador-at-large ambassador at large.

That's a different sense of "at large".  (unless the ambassador is a wanted criminal!)  This irrelevant, in the same way that the meaning of "give worksheets" is irrelevant to a question about using "pass out" instead of "faint" .

Of course it is and the OP didn't know that, which makes it relevant.

The news might also report that a dangerous animal that has escaped from the zoo and, after a failed search effort, the animal is still "at large"

It might,  but I think that would be a misuse

I don't know if other speakers have the same sense of the register of these phrases I do, but in American English there's a difference in register.  "At large" is something that might be said at a formal press conference, where the deputy chief of police, say, is giving a status update on a manhunt, whereas "on the loose" is somewhat gossipy.

AmE: Merriam Webster


at-large adjective ˈat-ˈlärj  : relating to or being a political
representative who is elected to serve an entire area rather than one
of its subdivisions an at-large city councilor an at-large election

Also, ambassador at large

And here: at large on Wikipedia
Collins Dictionary:

PHRASE If you say that a dangerous person, thing, or animal is at
large, you mean that they have not been captured or made safe. The man
who tried to have her killed is still at large.  Synonyms: free,
roaming, on the run, fugitive   More Synonyms of at large.

So, in some situations at large and on the loose are similar, not yet captured, a person or an animal (like a tiger).
Cambridge Dictionary:

be at large idiom
If someone dangerous is at large, that person is free when they should
not be: Twelve prisoners are at large following a series of escapes.

These terms are all explained in dictionaries.
